# Can Excel populate columns based off of a formula in a separate cell?

Tags: worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

In other words, can a formula dictate that the result be placed in a cell other than the cell the formula is written in?  In attempting to explore this on my own, I came across the following discussion thread:

[**Excel putting result of a formula in another Cell**](http://p2p.wrox.com/excel-vba/37251-excel-putting-result-formula-another-cell.html)

It would seem to me that there would be a way of doing this without resorting to VBA code (the suggestion in the thread).  For example, would the ADDRESS function be able to assist with this?  I'd be especially interested in knowing whether or not this would be possible for use with Excel 2007.

Comment: Hi Lisa - there are several ways to achieve this - the easiest is simple to type the resulting formula in the cell(s) you want the value to appear - say for example you have cells a1 & b1 with values and you want the result to appear is c1 - in c1 you could write '=a1/b1' which will place the result of dividing a1 with b1 in c1. The formula result can be as complex as you want it to be.

Comment: No, Built in Excel functions cannot put a value in a different cell than the one in which the formula is found.

Comment: @ScottCraner Without any disrespect/discounting of Jim's comment, I appreciate your easy to understand, direct answer and with a rep of 2,484 after just seven months, I'm going to assume you know what you're talking about.  Thank you for the quick, professional, courteous answer.